# Easy way to create a drop down box in HTML that simply comtains 0 to x?

Tags: javascript, html

I have happily created an HTML drop down box using the code below:

```
<select name=\"group\"> \
  <option value=\"10\">10</option> \
  <option value=\"11\">11</option> \
  <option value=\"33\">33</option> \
  <option value=\"Broadcast\">255</option> \
</select> \
```

However, my server is very limited as it's running on a small processor. I would like to create a dynamic drop down list that contain 0 to x, where x is the number of node on a bus I'm controlling. Is there any way to do that other than just dynamically creating the appropriate string to send out to the browser that adds extra lines such as:

```
<option value=\"x\">x</option> \
```

Where x is the next address of the node on the bus?

I'm wondering whether there's any way of writing some sort of HTML/Javascript code like this:

```
<dropdownbox="boxname", entries = x>
```

(The above is just some sort of psuedo code/ideal code, I'm not saying it's proper HTML!) That would just create a drop down box with x entries each entry would be labelled 0 to x.

The [real] HTML code looks a little odd as it's currently hard-coded into some C (I am going to make it dynamic for the next step). I should say that I know very little about HTML, I am just trying to knock up a very simple embedded server. I am open to sending some javascript or something else if it's easy to code that code into my C code. Any code has to be generated by a small processor for which I am writing the software in C and is being a little server.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed that will require some Javascript. Here is a working solution: if you manage to send that to the client (or have the JS function already part of the page), the code will read the `data-range` attribute of the `select` tag and create as many option nodes.

```html
<select id="mySelect" data-range="15" name="group"></select>

<script>
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var range = select.dataset.range;
  for (var i=0; i<+range; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("option");                
    node.value = i;
    node.text  = i;
    select.appendChild(node);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That works a treat when I quickly put it into my desktop running as a Web server, so it will be easy to put that into the C code on my embedded processor. I can even put that Javascript in <form> </form> with a button and it sends out the value of the drop-down box. Merci beacoup! :)